Comparing Qiskit gates with numpy functions
I am trying to understand how Qiskit's gates work by comparing the outputs of a simple circuit with numpy matrix algebra.
If I start with two qubits and apply a rotation gate to each of them, I get:
import numpy as np
import qiskit as qk
from qiskit.quantum_info.operators import Operator
from qiskit_aer import StatevectorSimulator

xlist = np.array([5,3])
x = xlist/np.linalg.norm(xlist)
y = 1/np.sqrt(2)*np.array([1,1])

circuit = qk.QuantumCircuit(2,1)
circuit.initialize(x, [0])
circuit.initialize(y, [1])

# apply rotations
theta = 0.313
H0 = np.array([[np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)], [np.sin(theta), -np.cos(theta)]])
H1 = np.array([[-np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)], [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]])
circuit.unitary(Operator(H0), [0], label='H0')
circuit.unitary(Operator(H1), [1], label='H1')

simulator = StatevectorSimulator()
job = qk.transpile(circuit, simulator)  # execute circuit on qasm simulator
result = simulator.run(job,shots=128).result()  # results from the job
out_state = result.get_statevector()
print(out_state)
circuit.draw(output='mpl')


The final state is
Statevector([-0.44330692+0.j,  0.10259143+0.j,  0.86755107+0.j,
             -0.2007713 +0.j],
            dims=(2, 2))

I'm trying to replicate this result by using numpy's functions:
x1 = np.array([[5],[3]])
x1 = x1/np.linalg.norm(x1)
y1 = 1/np.sqrt(2)*np.array([[1],[1]])
z1 = np.kron(x1, y1)
z1 = z1/np.linalg.norm(z1)

cx = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
z1 = np.matmul(cx, z1)  # entangled state??

# define 4x4 rotation matrix
rotate1 = np.zeros((4, 4))
rotate1[0:2, 0:2] = H0
rotate1[2:4, 2:4] = H1

# apply rotation
print(np.matmul(rotate1, z1))

The final state is
[[ 0.68889981]
 [-0.15942728]
 [-0.46485927]
 [ 0.53282817]]

Why does this not agree with the Qiskit result?  I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I know that z1 = np.matmul(cx, z1) gives a result that agrees with the circuit output (when there are no H0 and H1 gates).

Setting rotate1 to np.kron(H1, H0) outputs the correct result.
Your version of rotate1 does not represent the parallel application of H0 and H1, you need a tensor product of these gates, which is different from building a diagonal block matrix.
As of why you need to do np.kron(H1, H0) and not np.kron(H0, H1), I think it has to do with qiskit internally indexing the qubits in the order you do not expect.
